# Clone APEX-Application

Tags: oracle-apex

Is it possible to clone a existing APEX-Application for every user?
My company wants to use the applications I created to show Customers what we can do with APEX. So they want to give every customer access to the applications. Therefore I want to make shure, that the sample data I created is not changed, after they finished with there testing.

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 2):

If you just copy the apps in the same workspace then - even with separate apps - all the users will work on the same dataset. So that won't really be an option. Here are some possible approaches.

- To really separate the environments you could provision a separate workspace for every customer. That way they are all separated.
- You could also code a "reset test data" functionality in your app. Implement a procedure to delete and re-populate the your sample dataset. Might not be optimal if multiple users are testing things out at the same time.
- Or go for a "tenant" approach, where every customer has an tenant-id and only sees his rows in the application. Clean solution but more coding work.